# How to change the bar chart values from static to dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, charts

I have a code for a bar chart and it is working well but this code has static values but I want to take the values from a server and every time have a different chart (I mean I dont want to give any values in the code).How can I make that?
This is the code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>


$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Top 10 HashTags'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of repeated hashTags ',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 80,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [ {
            name: 'Year 2012',
            data: [1052, 954, 4250, 740, 38]
        }]
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little example to you. The first column is the xAxis and the others, series. I hope this help you.:

```
<?php
$sql5 = mysqli_query($bd,'SELECT tx_rend_escolas.ano, tx_rend_escolas.ap_med, tx_rend_escolas.rep_med, tx_rend_escolas.abd_med FROM tx_rend_escolas WHERE tx_rend_escolas.fk_cod_entidade = 21438200 ORDER BY tx_rend_escolas.ano ASC;') or die(mysqli_error());
$linhas5 = mysqli_num_rows($sql5);
$proc4 = array();
$proc5 = array();
$proc6 = array();
$proc7 = array();
while ($docs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql5)) {
        $proc4[] = "'".$docs['ano']."'";
        $proc5[] = $docs['ap_med'];
        $proc6[] = $docs['rep_med'];
        $proc7[] = $docs['abd_med'];
}
$proc4 = implode(",", $proc4);
$proc5 = implode(",", $proc5);
$proc6 = implode(",", $proc6);
$proc7 = implode(",", $proc7);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic and Estimated Worldwide Population Distribution by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [<?php echo $proc4;?>],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percent'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b><br/>',
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                lineColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#ffffff'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Aprovação',
            data: [<?php echo $proc5;?>]
        }, {
            name: 'Reprovação',
            data: [<?php echo $proc6;?>]
        }, {
            name: 'Abandono',
            data: [<?php echo $proc7;?>]
        }]
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it